Ошибка в проверки для BLUETOOTH_SCAN
Столкнулся с такой проблемой что, scanner?.startScan(filters, settings, callback) просит проверку на разрешения, но ошибка в this Уже всё перепробовал ничего не выход, что можно сделать?
Код который Android Studio даёт для проверки
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED{
return
}

Сам класс
class DevicesViewModel: ViewModel()

Нужен Context там.

@Style-7 я добавлял, но ничего не помогло

DevicesViewModel это не Context, поэтому this не прокатит. Эту проверку скорее всего надо делать где-нить в активити или фрагменте, который собирается BT scan запускать.

@EugeneKrivenja Хорошо, спасибо за ответ, попробую

Тут обьясняется как это все правильно делать: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
